# allow any php script instead of 404 page?

Tags: nginx, magento2.3.3, 404-page, .htaccess

I am trying a new local development method on windows using [magento 2 on vagrant on windows](https://onilab.com/blog/install-magento-2-on-localhost-a-windows-10-guide/) and it's up and running.  Now I'm trying to add xdebug with PHPstorm but it's unable to "see" an uploaded `phpinfo.php` file because all PHP files are disabled.

The `phpinfo.php` file is in `pub` but when viewing `http://myinstall.local/phpinfo.php` I get the 404 page and I'm trying to figure out where it is and to remove this as it's only a test system on my localhost.

I have commented out the last lines of `magento\nginx.conf`:
(note `magento` is the root folder on the installation)

```
# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
#location ~* (\.php$|\.txt$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
#    deny all;
#}
```

I've tried adding `phpinfo` to (what I believe are exclusions to being sent to eh main script) exclusion:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|phpinfo)\.php$ {
```

And of course I have restarted nginx:

```
vagrant@magento2-test:~/magento$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

> [ ok ] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.service.

I have confirmed that the error page is severed from `/errors/404.php` and so I've commented out the lines of `magento\.htaccess` and `magento\pub\.htaccess` that would use this:

```
# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
#ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
#ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404.php
```

In general the `.htaccess` seems to be allowing any specific file...

```
############################################
## Never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

...so I am now quite confused - can anyone please advise what else I could try to allow a random PHP file, or even a specific one like phpinfo.php, to serve from the `pub` folder please?